# How to deploy my php+mysql application for the end users in an easy-install way?

Tags: php, mysql, bitnami

It's a common task, and I explored this site, then I found a tool called "[BitNami Stacks](http://bitnami.org/stacks)" doing something like this, so I gave it a try.

I downloaded an installer with phpbb in it, and I started to install it, it works great! So, my question is:

1) How to modify the install wizard, so it can deploy my app instead of phpbb3?

2) How to use my language(Chinese in fact) instead of English in the wizard?

Of course, if BitNami can't do this, any other choice is welcome too.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Is your app using a framework. Some frameworks give you shell scripting features that you can use for that. Check you http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would produce my own linux .sh to:

1)wget a compressed archive of my script package included is a SQL with a known file name.

2) Extract to /var/www (or other set webdirectory)

2a) Prompt the user for a root password to SQL and save this to a variable

3) connect to SQL Database via this shell and `cat filename.sql | mysql -u root -p pass-variable`

4) `RM -f /var/www/ filename.sql`  to delete the raw SQL file

*Everything you want done can be done via bash scripting, which is technically what the link you provided does*

On windows, I wouldn't know how to approach this.

Comment: My end users are almost using windows :)